# Creating an list of dictionaries that hold a variable sized array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, dictionary

I'm trying to create the following data structure (that's not optimal, I know, but is necessary given my input data):

A list of 100 dictionaries with the same two keys, "x" and "y", where each key holds a variable length numpy array. "y" holds a vector and "x" holds an array of images, so an example shape for x could be 10 x 3 x 10 x 50, or, 10 RGB images of size 10 by 50. An example shape for the corresponding y would be 10, because the initial lengths of the x and y need to be the same. If I have only 8 images, then the length of y is also 8, etc.

I want to preinitialize this structure so I can fill it in with changed data values, and do it so that I can set the size of the variable length "x" and "y" arrays for each dictionary based on a separate piece of input data. I know that I can set the dictionary with something like this:

```
imageArray = np.zeros(10,3,10,50)

vectorNumbers = np.zeros(10)

output = [{'x':imageArray,'y':vectorNumbers}]
```

So that should create a single dictionary, but if I have something like an array with the lengths of the dictionary values "x" and "y", how can I use something like this:

```
 output = [{'x':imageArray,'y':vectorNumbers} for k in range(listLength)]
```

But ensure that the imageArray length would be [variable,3,10,50] and the vectorNumbers length would be [variable], where variable is the number stored in another list that I can access thanks to the k counter above.

Comment: This puts the same arrays in each dictionary.  Change values in one will change the values in all.  I don't think you want that. You need to create a new array, with the right dimensions, for each dictionary.  With lists and dictionaries you can't take short cuts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input list of lengths is a list of pairs, or something similar.

```
input_lengths = [(12,17), (8,50), (2,7)]
pre_filled_list = [{'x' : [None]*x, 'y' : [None]*y} for x,y in input_lengths]
print(pre_filled_list)
```

Pre_filled list is a list of dictionaries, each with two keys; each value is a list of None of the desired length.

Comment: `x` and `y` are supposed to be 4d and 1d numpy arrays, not lists.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import numpy as np

dims = [(42,43), (46,9), (47,49), (60,14)]
output = [{'x':np.zeros((x,3,10,50)), 'y':np.zeros((y,))} for (x,y) in dims]

print(len(output))              # 4, matches len(dims)

print(type(output[0]['x']))     # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(output[0]['y']))     # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(output[0]['x'].shape)     # (42, 3, 10, 50)
                                #  42 is from the first element of the first tuple in dims
print(output[0]['y'].shape)     # (43,)
                                #  43 is from the second element of the first tuple in dims

print(output[1]['x'].shape)     # (46, 3, 10, 50)
print(output[1]['y'].shape)     # (9,)
```

The arrays are in the dictionaries, which are in the list.  All zeros of the dimensions (I think) you want.

If you want something closer to what you had, with `range(listLength)`, these four lines produce the same output as above:

```
xd = [42, 46, 47, 60]
yd = [43,  9, 49, 14]
listLength = 4

output=[{'x':np.zeros((xd[k],3,10,50)),'y':np.zeros((yd[k],))} for k in range(listLength)]
```